# How to integrate the external library (like cmph) inside OVS?

Tags: c, makefile, openvswitch

I have OVS source code and CMPH source code. Each of it has its own MakeFile. My intuition is somehow I need to include CMPH information in OVS make file and build OVS so that I can use CMPH inside OVS.

I need to use CMPH library for perfect hashing in OVS, but I am new to the C and MAKE world. I tried googling out the process but so far have not got any concrete help. It would be great if anyone can provide how to work towards the problem. I only need some initial steps on how to start tackling this problem. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: How is CMake related to the problem? If no relation, why `cmake` tag?

Comment: sorry. I removed the tag.